# Beanstalkd "delayed job" doesn't execute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, beanstalkd

I'm having some issues getting a job to run in my Laravel 4 setup. I have it working on Homestead, however it doesn't work on production. I'm using Beanstalkd (with pheanstalk), and Supervisor, following [this tutorial](http://posts.danharper.me/laravel-queue-supervisor).

In a nutshell, I want to delete an image which is on my server, 20 seconds after the job has been called.

```
Queue::later(20, 'App\Queues\FileHandler@delete', ['file' => $file]);
```

`$file` is the path to my file.

My delete method:

```
public function delete($job, $data)
{
    var_dump($data);
    if (File::exists($data['file']))
        File::delete($data['file']);

    $job->delete();
}
```

I also installed [Beanstalkd Console](https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console).

Right, so when I click the button, it triggers the queue. I can see on the console the console that it now has the correct `$data`, with the correct path to the file.

On the console, the `time-left` counts down from 20... and when it hits 0, it resets to a very large number (18446744073666). There is no errors/output in the logs.

As soon as I "kick" the job from the console, it executes and my file deletes, so I know the code is sound.

Anyone got any suggestions, its really annoying me :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 1.4.6 had an issue with delayed jobs. Upgrade to 1.5 or 1.6 if your running on 1.4.6

Comment: Thanks. Issue was on 1.4.6 it seems!

Comment: Ok this may be dumb but how does one upgrade from 1.4.6? `apt-get install beanstalkd` just gave me 1.4.6. Do I have to manually download it?

Comment: Yes, or find a place where you can download a newer one from another distro. I had to move heaven and earth to get a newer version working. https://launchpad.net/~jernej/+archive/ubuntu/beanstalkd/+packages helped me.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem using debian wheezy. Adding `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jernej/beanstalkd/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main`  to the  `/etc/apt/sources.list` helped. To detect the right ubuntu version for the debain version installed this was very usefull[link](https://askubuntu.com/a/445496/413377). Hopefully this helps the next one :-)